# Why do I get the error "Request had insufficient authentication scopes." when accessing the Google Sheets API through Python?

Tags: google-sheets-api

For reference, I'm using code from the Google Developer Forums found [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values). This is the code built to work with the Sheets API, which is the one I'm using.

Reading sheets works fine, but as soon as I begin trying to write to a sheet, I get trouble. I get the following error:

HttpError 403 when requesting [redacted sheet link] returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

However, the *only* authentication scope that the OAuth credentials the program is using is the one ending in:

/auth/spreadsheet

I'm struggling to find the whole scope, but point is it can read but not write. What should I do to fix this?

Code used (slightly modified from the actual dev forum code):

```
def writesheet(sheet_id, sheet_range, value_input_option, writable_info=None, scopes=None):
    # writable_info is left blank for now just to use a test set of data    
    if writable_info is None:
        writable_info = [
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            [6, 7, None, 9, 10],
            [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
        ]
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', scopes)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
    body = {
    'values': writable_info
    }
    result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
        spreadsheetId=sheet_id, range=sheet_range,
        valueInputOption=value_input_option, body=body).execute()
    print('{0} cells updated.'.format(result.get('updatedCells')))


writesheet('1IOzqQt1Jlb6hejjnAc1AunjkGKhtgvmTumnrT6SwQno', 'Sheet1!A1:E3', "RAW")
```

Comment: In your script, unfortunately, I cannot confirm the value of `SCOPES` and `scopes`. Can you provide the whole script including `SCOPES` and `scopes`? By the way, in your script, 2 variables of `SCOPES` and `scopes` are used. In this case, both values are the same or different?